# Why can I pull the mouse off the drag area in this script?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, drag, gecko

Using a plain JS script from David Flanagan to make my bookmarklet draggable.

I have noticed that I can move the pointer off the drag bar during key-down and the pop-up may or may not follow the pointer around or suddenly snap to the pointer.

The total experience in Firefox 8 and 9 is not impressive. IE8 on XP works as designed

It is intended for a bookmarklet, so I canot use a framework like jQuery or YUI.

**QUESTION:** How do I improve the stickyness of the mousedown / drag so the window stays attached to the mouse onmousedown and onmousemove using plain JS?

Also please help me make the getLeft and getTop work in IE/Chrome and Fx so the popup is restricted to the viewport.

[OLD DEMO HERE](http://plungjan.name/SO/zdrag.html)

[NEW AND FIXED DEMO HERE](http://plungjan.name/SO/zdrag2.html) (thanks techfoobar)

```
function getTop(top) {
//  if (console) console.log('y:'+top+':'+document.body.clientHeight);  
  if (top<0) return 0;
  if (top>=(document.body.clientHeight-40)) return document.body.clientHeight-40;
  return top;
}
function getLeft(left) {
//  if (console) console.log('x:'+left+':'+document.body.clientWidth);  
  if (left<0) return 0;
  if (left>=(document.body.clientWidth-500)) return document.body.clientWidth-500;
  return left;
}
// This code is from the book JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition (ISBN #978-0596805524). Copyright 2011 by David Flanagan.
function getScrollOffsets(w) {
  w = w || window;
  if (w.pageXOffset != null) return {x: w.pageXOffset, y:w.pageYOffset};
  var d = w.document;
  if (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat") 
    return {x:d.documentElement.scrollLeft, y:d.documentElement.scrollTop};
  return { x: d.body.scrollLeft, y: d.body.scrollTop };
}

function zDrag(elementToDrag, event) { var scroll = getScrollOffsets();
  var startX = event.clientX + scroll.x;
  var startY = event.clientY + scroll.y;
  var origX = elementToDrag.offsetLeft;
  var origY = elementToDrag.offsetTop;
  var deltaX = startX - origX;
  var deltaY = startY - origY;
  if (document.addEventListener) { 
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", upHandler, true);
  } 
  else if (document.attachEvent) { 
    elementToDrag.setCapture();
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);
  } 
  if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
  else event.cancelBubble = true;
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  else event.returnValue = false;

  function moveHandler(e) { 
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var scroll = getScrollOffsets();
    elementToDrag.style.left = getLeft(e.clientX + scroll.x - deltaX,true) + "px";
    elementToDrag.style.top = getTop(e.clientY + scroll.y - deltaY,true) + "px";
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
  };
  function upHandler(e) { 
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (document.removeEventListener) { 
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", upHandler, true);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler, true);
    } 
    else if (document.detachEvent) { 
      elementToDrag.detachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);
      elementToDrag.detachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
      elementToDrag.detachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
      elementToDrag.releaseCapture();
    } 
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
   };
 } 
  // end drag code
```

Comment: So your question applies to Firefox only, or..?

Comment: Possibly other browsers than IE. IE8 works fine

Comment: Please make your code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should take care of the stickiness issue.

I could see from your demo site that when the mouse is over the inner iframe, we have an issue with stickiness. This is because the inner iframe does not bubble the event up to the root document element which handles zDrag's mousemove event.

I solved that issue by appending an overlay div (invisible but there) that takes the entire area of the root document, thereby effectively preventing the inner iframe from getting the mousemove. And as this overlay div is a direct descendant of our root document element, it bubbles up the mousemove event correctly.

Changes include an additional method for getting the document height (from http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/), and changes to the zDrag method for adding/showing/hiding the overlay div.

```
function getDocHeight() {
  var D = document;
  return Math.max(
    Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
}

function zDrag(elementToDrag, event) { 
  var scroll = getScrollOffsets();

  // create/show overlay - over the inner iframe and everything else
  var div = document.getElementById('overlay');
  if(div==null) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'overlay';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.left = '0px';
    div.style.top = '0px';
    div.style.width = '100%';
    div.style.height = getDocHeight()+'px';
    div.style.zIndex = 99999;
    div.style.cursor = 'move';
    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    bodyTag.appendChild(div);
  }
  else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }

  var startX = event.clientX + scroll.x;
  var startY = event.clientY + scroll.y;
  var origX = elementToDrag.offsetLeft;
  var origY = elementToDrag.offsetTop;
  var deltaX = startX - origX;
  var deltaY = startY - origY;
  if (document.addEventListener) { 
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", upHandler, true);
  } 
  else if (document.attachEvent) { 
    /*elementToDrag.setCapture();
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
    elementToDrag.attachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);*/

    // attach the events to the document element, to ensure we dont 'miss' any move events.
    document.setCapture();
    document.attachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
    document.attachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
    document.attachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);
  } 

  if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
  else event.cancelBubble = true;
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  else event.returnValue = false;

  function moveHandler(e) { 
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var scroll = getScrollOffsets();
    elementToDrag.style.left = getLeft(e.clientX + scroll.x - deltaX,true) + "px";
    elementToDrag.style.top = getTop(e.clientY + scroll.y - deltaY,true) + "px";
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
  };

  function upHandler(e) { 

    // dragging is over. hide the overlay.
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';

    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (document.removeEventListener) { 
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", upHandler, true);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveHandler, true);
    } 
    else if (document.detachEvent) { 
      /*elementToDrag.detachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);
      elementToDrag.detachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
      elementToDrag.detachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
      elementToDrag.releaseCapture();*/
      document.detachEvent("onlosecapture", upHandler);
      document.detachEvent("onmouseup", upHandler);
      document.detachEvent("onmousemove", moveHandler);
      document.releaseCapture();

    } 
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
  };
}
```

**EDIT - For limiting the drag inside the viewport**

Now it will limit the dragging to inside the viewport (i.e browser window inner width and height). Changes include a) an additional cross-browser function to get the window inner width and height (from http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) and b) changes to the moveHandler() method (inside the zDrag method) to check and enforce limits.

```
function getWindowSize() {
  var winW = 630, winH = 460;
  if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
    winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
    winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
  }
  if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
    winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
    winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  }
  if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
    winW = window.innerWidth;
    winH = window.innerHeight;
  }
  return {width: winW, height: winH};
}
```

And inside zDrag(), replace the current moveHandler with:

```
function moveHandler(e) { 
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var scroll = getScrollOffsets();

  var newLeft = getLeft(e.clientX + scroll.x - deltaX,true);
  if(newLeft + elementToDrag.offsetWidth > winDim.width) {
    newLeft = winDim.width - elementToDrag.offsetWidth;
  }
  elementToDrag.style.left = newLeft + "px";

  var newTop = getTop(e.clientY + scroll.y - deltaY,true);
  if(newTop + elementToDrag.offsetHeight > winDim.height) {
    newTop = winDim.height - elementToDrag.offsetHeight;
  }
  elementToDrag.style.top = newTop + "px";

  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
  else e.cancelBubble = true;
};
```

**EDIT - the winDim variable**

winDim is the variable that stores the viewport's dimensions. It is used in the move handler to check if our movable is within the viewport. I kept it outside so as to avoid re-computation of window dimensions on every move event which could degrade performance.

```
var winDim = null;

function zDrag(...) {

  if(winDim == null) winDim = getWindowSize

  // ... rest of the code in zDrag ...

}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you I will test this. When I saw "overlay" I thought - oh no, that will stop interaction with the iframe, but of course it should work if you hide/remove it when the drag stopped.

Comment: BTW, i have checked it only in FF (i write almost all my code/css in firebug first!). If testing in IE, you might need to remove the setCapture and releaseCapture calls.

Comment: So I removed the comments and deleted the document.setCapture you changed and it seems to behave well in all 3 browsers. Can you as a bonus, fix the right/bottom limiter so I cannot move it off the bottom or the right? Please use the new version [here](http://plungjan.name/SO/zdrag1.html)

Comment: Did you just change your name?

Comment: Yeah :) I changed my display name to the name of my blog!

Comment: Where are we using getWindowSize? What to do with the getTop and getLeft I wrote - seems they can be scrapped or replaced... I cannot give you the bounty until 15 hours from now or so... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oops. I missed out the winDim part. winDim is the variable that stores the window's dimensions. When i updated my answer, i forgot to copy that part over! I have updated my answer to include it. And getWindowSize() function can be considered as a cross-browser variant of getTop and getLeft put together.

Comment: Thanks. I would like if you would take a look at the version that [now is running](http://plungjan.name/SO/zdrag2.html) - I have tested in Fx9 on OSX and it runs well except I can slide the mouse to the right when I am a scrollbar's width to the right of the screen
Also I have a feeling we can cut down on helper functions!

Comment: Do you mean you are able to move it only till (screenWidth-scrollBarWidth) and not the whole screen width? Will it be possible to share a screen shot? Also, on which all browser do you get this? Regarding helpers, yes i think we can inline both `getDocHeight()` as well as `getWindowSize()` as both of them are called just once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5932/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-techfoobar)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the iframe. When the mouse pointer enters that you say goodbye to all your registered events. Replace the iframe with a div and things should improve in Firefox. IE simply seems to update the display faster; the mouse pointer never gets the chance to enter the iframe in IE.

Comment: But the mouse pointer should not get the chance to enter the iframe since I do the mousedown on the div and that should glue the point of the mousedown to the pointer. I must use an iframe for zindex reasons

Comment: IE6 huh? Well leave the iframe in but cover it with a div.